# XML документация кода с generics

Tags: c#, документация

Есть проект на c# с подробной документацией в xml, вот пример документации:

```
    /// ... - много-много текста
    /// <example>
    /// Классический пример использования:
    /// <code>
    ///     
    ///     public delegate void MyDelegateMethod(int value);
    ///     ...
    ///     
    ///     Type type = assembly.GetType("Data.Test");
    ///     MyDelegateMethod fooMethod = type.GetMethod<MyDelegateMethod>("Foo");
    ///     fooMethod.Invoke(42);
    ///     
    /// </code>
    /// </example>
    public static T GetMethod<T>(this Type type, string name) where T : class {
        return GetMethod<T>(type,name,true);
    }
```

Далее, есть VisualStudio нескольких версий - 2012 и 2015. Так вот, с точки зрения XML данные доки ошибочны, так как генерик-метод:

```
type.GetMethod<MyDelegateMethod>("Foo");
```

интерпретируется как открытие тега MyDelegateMethod, который, не закрывается.

Скрин из MS Visual Studio 2012, при попытке прочитать документацию всплывающим контекстом:
[image: Ошибка, тег MyDelegateMethod не закрыт]

С точки зрения документации - всё чисто (код написан в ограничивающих тегах <code> </code>).

В поисках истины, прочитал я рекомендации с англоязычных ресурсов:

- [Замена символов '<' и '>' на &lt и &gt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33418668/how-to-properly-escape-the-content-of-a-code-example-in-xml-documentation)
- [Замена символов '<' и '>' внутри генерик на '{' и '}'](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/xml-documentation-comments)

Но, всё это сделает код внутри тегов <code> не рабочим. (Что это значит - найдётся горе-программист, который скопирует код из этой документации и искренне удивится что без редактирования этот код не работает ни под одним из существующих шарпов) Кроме того, код вида:

```
MyDelegateMethod fooMethod = type.GetMethod<MyDelegateMethod>("Foo");
```

воспринимается сразу, и без серьёзных рассуждений, в свою очередь, код такого вида:

```
MyDelegateMethod fooMethod = type.GetMethod&lt;MyDelegateMethod&gt;("Foo");
```

сходу сложно определить.

Подскажите, как лучше вести документацию подобного рода, и каким образом сделать код одновременно и читаемым, и логичным с точки зрения xml?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Для тегов наподобие `<see cref="...">` вам [нужно использовать `{}`-синтаксис](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/cref-attribute), он не зависит от языка (C#/VB/...) и распознаётся парсером документации.

```
/// <summary>
/// Uses class <see cref="Range{T}"/>
/// </summary>
```

Для примеров кода лучше всего, вероятно, использовать блок CDATA:

```
/// <example>
/// <code>
/// <![CDATA[
/// new Test<T>(new Range<T>().Go());
/// ]]>
/// </code>
/// </example>
```

Comment: Именно то что нужно! Огромное спасибо за подсказку)

Comment: @test123: Пожалуйста, рад, что помогло!